# Unexpected tIDENTIFIER using Faker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning how to seed data into my project using the faker gem.  My project is a todo list that allows users to checkoff and add items.  I learned how to create my own RandomData but I'm having trouble adapting a gem into the tutorial.

Please forgive me if I'm blatantly missing something from this, I've only been learning Ruby on Rails for a few months now.

Error:

```
myapp/app/models/item.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
  validates :description presence: true
```

I checked with my mentor and they said my item.rb is fine with the space for `validates :description presence: true`.
Contents of item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :description presence: true
end
```

My seeds.rb file contents:

```
#Create fake users
5.times do
  user = User.new(
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
  )
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
end

#Create fake items
10.times do
  item = Item.create!(
    user: users.sample,
    name: Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{User.count} users created"
puts "#{Item.count} items created"
```

What am I missing? What can I do better?

Comment: You're missing basic Ruby syntax rules and error message interpretation. No offense :) `myapp/app/models/item.rb`, 3rd line, take a closer look.

Comment: I had no idea I was even missing that comma, thus why I asked.

Comment: Then you might want to read a book about Ruby before proceeding further. That might save you quite a bit of time. "Beginning Ruby" or "A well-grounded Rubyist" for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validates :description presence: true
```

You are missing comma after **:description**

**Error explained**

```
myapp/app/models/item.rb:3: syntax error,
```

You have syntax error on line 3 of item.rb

```
unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
```

Ruby interpreter was looking for keyword_end but it didn't find it

```
validates :description presence: true
```

And the line so you can check your syntax